# Node.js Callback Failing - Function pass Variables with Callback

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm new to Node.js and I'm struggling to get a callback to work. I have the following function call:

```
memberPhotoPath(dbResults[i].userid2,dbResults[i].userid2Gender,'small',dbResults[i].userid2PhotoName,dbResults[i].userid2PhotoVerified,false,function(path) {
    console.log(path);    
});
```

and the following function:

```
function memberPhotoPath(userid,gender,photoSize,photoName,photoVerification,border,callback) {
    if(photoVerification) {
        callback('http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-photos/'+userid+'/'+userid+'-'+photoSize+'-'+photoName+'.jpg');
    }else{
        if(border) {
            if(gender) {
                callback('http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-website/default-female-image-'+photoSize+'.png');
            }else{
                callback('http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-website/default-male-image-'+photoSize+'.png');
            }
        }else{
            if(gender) {
                callback('http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-website/default-female-image-'+photoSize+'-noborder.png');
            }else{
                callback('http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-website/default-male-image-'+photoSize+'-noborder.png');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error in Node.js:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at memberPhotoPath (/etc/node/index.js:315:5)
    at /etc/node/index.js:223:21
    at memberPhotoPath (/etc/node/index.js:315:5)
    at /etc/node/index.js:214:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /etc/node/index.js:208:34
    at Query._callback (/etc/node/index.js:287:9)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:75:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:127:8)
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just run this code in the chrome console and it works fine. The error must be somewhere down the line. With asynchronous functions it is sometimes not possible to track the exact stack trace. I advise you brace yourself and go through your other code again